# Is is necessary to have the 'const' in declaring char const *ptr = "some characters"?

Tags: c++, c

Since they both point to characters which can not be modified. What is the benefit of having the const in the first one? Is it just to tell the compiler to watch out for any code that may do something like `ptr[1] = 'a'`

1. `char const *ptr = "some characters"`
2. `char *ptr = "some characters"`

Comment: In the 2nd case you can't modify the contents of ptr only because the section in which "some characters" was placed is read only. For example, an access violation is thrown on Windows when trying to modify the contents of it. Perhaps there are some esoteric platforms in which you could get away doing that.

Comment: @Kostya - yes thanks. Is it an access violation or undefined behaviour?

Comment: @Kostya: Many platforms do have flags to actually allow this; I'd be surprised if MSVC didn't. Still, it's a very bad idea.

Comment: @MeThinks: It is always undefined behavior to modify a `const`, and the string literal is `const` even if the pointer is not. On Windows under default compiler flags, Kostya is saying it is an access violation. You should never see an access violation under conditions that are not undefined behavior.

Comment: `C` or `C++` (maybe `COBOL` or `Java` or ...)? The answer is different depending on language.

Comment: @pmg The question is tagged c and c++ but insight into other languages will only make me learn something new which is definitely a good thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, so that when you try to modify the contents through the pointer you will get a compiler error instead of nasty surprises at the run time.

Comment: Thanks. The very real advantage of 'catching' the error at compile time is a compelling reason to use it for me especially as the result of trying to modify characters results in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, the conversion of `const char[N]`, which is the actual type of a string literal, to `char *`, is deprecated and no longer works in C++11 (C++11, C++03 §4.2). So, #2 is newly broken. A C++98/C++03 compiler usually produces a warning; a C++0x/C++11 compiler should refuse entirely.

The main point of `const` is that the compiler can tell you when an attempt is made to remove or violate it. Even if you don't plan to try to modify those characters, the advantage is that an error occurs if you accidentally do.

You can always work around it with `const_cast`, although in this case where the memory is likely to be read-only, physically or via the MMU, there cannot be anything to work around.

Answer (score 2):

The use of `const` is very rarely "necessary", from a pure "executing this code will have the desired results" point of view.

Copious use of `const` is an immense help to anyone reading the code an trying to understand it, however. This is worth a lot. I recommend always putting `const` everywhere it will work.

In a similar vein, always declare functions that are intended to be strictly local as `static`, for pretty much the same reason.

Comment: Yes!Yes!Yes!  Too many coders skimp on the consts because they "don't do anything".  But from the point of view of being documentation which is checked by the compiler... priceless!

Answer (score 1):

This is recommended:

```
char const *ptr = "some characters";
```

And the following is **not** recommended, as you might try to change the **const** data `ptr` points to.

```
char *ptr = "some characters";
```

Good compilers should give warning in the second case.

GCC (4.3.4) does give warning:

> prog.cpp:7: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’

See yourself : http://www.ideone.com/8FqyZ

Comment: Why? The warning? a string literal is a value of type `char[]`. When used in most contexts it decays into a pointer to its first element (`char*`). The assignment of a value of type `char*` to an object of type `char*` should be warning free.

Comment: It's legal and has defined behavior, so define "wrong". It's pretty much always a bad idea, it's ultimately only there for compatibility with pre-`const` non-standard versions of C, it's deprecated in C++, and it's a hole in the type system. But apart from that it's OK ;-)

Comment: @pmg: C++ differs from C in this respect. In C++ a string literal has type `const char[]`, but there is a deprecated implicit conversion to `char*` for compatibility with C. I know you're a C person, so you're mercifully saved from having to know about these annoying differences :-)

Comment: @Steve, thanks for that. I usually pay closer attention to the tags (and try to stay away from things I don't know) and specify C in my answers / comments.

Answer (score 0):

It's to tell the compiler to watch out for any code that may try and change the string.
Although, you can be clever and still change the string, but normally it's to prevent accidental bugs in your code.

Answer (score 0):

In `C` both definitions below are perfectly legal and reasonable.

```
char const *ptr1 = "some characters";
char *ptr2 = "some characters";
```

In `C`, a string literal is a value of type `char[]`. In most uses it decays to a value of type `char*`. Adding the `const` modifier is, to many people, a good habit to get into: it gets the compiler to complain if the code attempts to change the string literal (which is undefined behaviour).